Unknown object in Excel 2021 cells
In creating a very simple excel sheet in Excel 2021, I am now seeing a small bold cross (Not the one for copy/drag) in several cells. It will neither cut nor delete. It does not enlarge or change with the font. When I left click, it opens a vertical line with several symbols on it. At the top is the rotate symbol. In the middle are 4 connected circles which allow a picture of the symbol to be enlarged. At the bottom are 4 arrows that allow one to move a copy of the symbol to any other location on the sheet. The copies can be cut, but the original remains and cannot be cut or deleted. It seems that left clicking on the symbol only opens it as a copy of the symbol in picture format in a textbox. Right click allows the cut option but does not work. Copying an existing cell into it add the new data but the symbol remains. Thoughts? I need it to go away. Thank you.

Sounds like it might be an object of some sort, maybe one with zero width. Can you maybe upload a screencap to http://imgur.com and link to it?

Not knowledgeable enough for that. Could I email it to you?

No. That would defeat the purpose of this site. Imgur is pretty straightforward to use. Try it!
